# Cannot Change the Flovour size of VM using libvirt

Tags: openstack, libvirt

I am trying to resize a VM instance(change flavor) on one of the nodes, which is upon OpenStack KVM Hypervisor.

I need to resize the instance without rebooting it. I did not find any commands which would resize the instance without rebooting. Libvirt API does increase the size of VM till its maximum memory in the flavor, but it doesnt change the flavor to higher one.

Can any one help me in changing the flavor name dynamically without rebooting the instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a snapshot of the vm, then start the snpshot with larger flavor. Finally remove the first vm.